# Não estou conseguindo obter o token com AsyncStorage no React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, asyncstorage

Tentei usar async/await e também não deu certo. Então tentei com callback. Num primeiro momento consigo visualizar o token com `console.log(item)`, porém `console.log(token)` retorna `undefined`.

Como posso fazer com que o token seja alocado na variável declarada abaixo ?

```
   let token;
   AsyncStorage.getItem('AUTH', (err, item) => {
     console.log(item)
     token = item;
    
    });
   console.log(token);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não sei o que você quer fazer, mas vou supor que seja um login usando o token.

`await AsyncStorage.setItem("save",JSON.stringify(r))` esse `r` é os dados de login do usuário junto com o token e no `useEffect` (na mesma pagina) estou pegando assim:

```
const ttSave = async () => {
  const r = await AsyncStorage.getItem("save");
  const e = JSON.parse(r)//JSON.parse por causa do JSON.stringify
  if(e){
    navigation.navigate('Home', {Home:e})//"Home" seria a pagina seguinte
  }
}

useEffect(()=>{
  ttSave();
}, [])
```

Na pagina seguinte você deverá usar o header para pegar o token, tem com o fetch e o Axios, no fetch seria assim

```
const token = Home.token;// 'Home' é o parametro do usuario

useEffect(()=>{
    fetch('sua url', {
        method: 'get',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type':'application/json',
            "Authorization":`Bearer ${token}`
        }
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(res => {setDocs(res)})
    .catch(err=>{})
}, [])
```

já com o axios eu nunca tentei.

Comment: Estou recebendo "can't find variable Home"  ao mudar para a rota Home.

Comment: se tiver usando reactnavigation versão 4 será assim 
const id = navigation.getParam('Home');)
se for a versão 5 será assim (
const { Home } = route.params;
)// substitua o {navigation por route} ou pode deixar os dois